# How to fetch JSON data in chain of links and put it to the same model?

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurlsessiondatatask, urlsession

I don't know how to put  it correctly so I will show in pictures.

I create first `URLSession`, fetch data from `JSON`, including links to data I want to use in the same Model.

first link:

[image: SchreenShot]

From first request I got links to other info I want to use in the same table:

links from first link:

[image: ScreenShot]

I'm trying to fetch data from both first and second link and put it together in one data model/table/cell.

I need to make another `URLSession`, but I can't understood how put info together.
Is it possible to fire one `URLSession` inside another? Any suggestions how to make it?

Comment: please add your code also as text. select the code and press the button `{}` then it gets an indention of 4 spaces and is displayed as code. (you can leave the images)

Comment: ok - json data is free on the api homepage

Comment: Send a notice to delete this question since I want describe problem with code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using some libraries to abstract some complexity - [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)/[SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
switch response.result {
case .success(let value):
    let json = JSON(value)
    //pull your links out of the json and make another request here
    Alamofire.request(json["fixtures"]["competition"]["href"], method: .get).responseJSON { response in
       switch response.result {
          case .success(let value): 
          let json2 = JSON(value)
          //handle the json from your second request
        }
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that this is pseudo code.  Don't try to cut and paste - but it should get you in the general direction.

Comment: Its something i thought about, put second URLSession into another. But app crashed with findind null unwrapping some variable.

Comment: SwiftyJSON will help with parsing JSON and safely unwrapping null.  But, without your actual code, its impossible to help you out more.

Answer (score 0):

create a `job queue` where you place your task (=Retrieve Data) into.

start the queue with your root url call. when it comes back from async call, parse the JSON data - populate your local structs as data holder. and the next 1 or 2 links to follow you put in the queue.

maybe remember the already retrieved URL in a Array so you can check that you don't read some data twice.

NOTE: there is a call rate limit on the api site. if you create an public app then you should think how to serverside cache all the calls to be under 50/24h or 50/1min

Comment: Its not public, just for training.

Comment: So the logic is: start first session, put task into custom created queue, retrieve data, put it in struct, then i create another task to retrieve more deep level data. Where should i reload table and how populate cells? Just put some data from one struct and some data from other? But the problem is i need to do something like array of tasks. For example today its 8 games, 16 teams, i need 16 tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution, should use 'dispatch group'.